# ASP.NET Imagemap blocked by Kaspersky anti-virus software

Tags: asp.net, antivirus, imagemap

Has anyone experienced problems with Kaspersky anti-virus stopping browsers from displaying imagemaps created in an ASP.NET app?  And if so, is there a way round this?

Many thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the firewall. Generally its the firewall which created the problem.

A firewall may prevent some content of your website from being accessible, so if you have problems with accessing content then check that your firewall is not rejecting content form your site.

The easiest way to ensure that your firewall is not blocking your access to ur site services is to use your firewall control panel to allow data from *.(your site url)

Comment: I dare say, but why? Ideally I want to be able to implement the web site such that anyone can view the imagemap, irrespective of their fire wall or anti-virus configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my question was invalid after all.  The problem was with the specific png file that was being used on the imagemap.  Kaspersky wouldn't display it under any circumstances (although I couldn't find anything wrong with it). When I converted it to a jpeg everything worked as it should.